# Java: How to convert MySQL DECIMAL(39,0) IP address to String

Tags: java, mysql, networking

So I'm told that the DBAs here are going to be storing IP addresses in a DECIMAL(39,0) field in our MySQL database.

How can I go about translating that into a String to pass on to our other applications?

Note: Our databases can't take any more load, so as much of the work as possible needs to be done in the Java application.

Note2: IPv6 support is a must.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved, I convinced the database guys to just store it as a VARCHAR instead.

Comment: I was attempting to construct an IPv6 number to address converter. Like I said earlier, it is doable with BigDecimal (that maps to the MySQL DECIMAL type), but it is a toughie.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
INET_NTOA
```

eg: SELECT INET_NTOA(num) AS ipaddr;

and

```
INET_ATON
```

eg: INSERT INTO addrTbl VALUES (..., INET_ATON('192.168.0.1'), ...)

This works because IPv4 was originally designed to have IP addresses defined as 32-bit numbers. The [dot-decimal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) is for readbility.

**Update**

If you wish to perform the transformation from a number to a dot-decimal notation in Java, the [MindProd site has an example](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/ip.html#DISPLAYING).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention though... using MySQL function calls or stored procedures is absolutely out of the question. Our database memory is at a premium.

Comment: I've updated the answer, assuming that you intend to do this in Java.

Comment: That is more helpful, but still doesn't really cut it. Do you know of any methods that have IPv6 support?

Comment: That's a bit difficult with primitives (due to 128 bit sizes for IPv6 addresses), but doable.

Comment: I'm up voting you but only because you added the link to MindPro where the answer actually is! :)